# How to implement context menus on Table Using [React+Typescript]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

Using [React+Typescript] I need to implement context menus on Table [on click on row cell and column header].

Looked several libraries:
ag grid provides context menus in enterprise version, that to on rows cell only.
react-data-grid provides row level context menus. but this lib is having poor doc maintenance,it makes difficult to develop

can any on please suggest how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually achieve what you are looking for with AG-Grid (even without the enterprise version).

We are currently using AG-Grid (free version) for our Tables and it has the possibility to display context menus as you are able to write your own cell renderer functions with AG-Grid. (Column renderer functions respectively).
These Cell renderers can be written in both React or plain Javascript.

If you write the Cell Renderer yourself you are in full control of what happens on interaction with any given cell.

You can even implement more complex Cell renderers that interact with the user in various ways.

Here is a link to read more: 
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/

Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: 
**I am not in any way affiliated with AG-Grid or its developers.**